# Styling Tab Widget's using XML

Tags: android, android-theme, android-tabs, android-styles, tabwidget

So I am having great difficultly styling tab widgets using xml. Everywhere I have searched seem's to either suggest solutions to do this programmatically, or refers to the actionBarTab style >:|

What I am trying to achieve is a customised tab from the tabwidget drawables that was generated using http://android-holo-colors.com/

I manage to get the

So in my custom theme I have this code:

```
<style name="RR.App.Theme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
...
<item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/RR.Tab.Widget</item>
...
</style>
```

This is the RR.Tab.Widget style: (none of these seem to make such difference)

```
<style name="RR.Tab.Widget" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TabWidget">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/rrtheme_tab_indicator_holo</item>
<item name="android:tabStripEnabled">false</item>
<item name="android:tabStripLeft">@null</item>
<item name="android:tabStripRight">@null</item>
</style>
```

This is the generated drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/rrtheme_tab_unselected_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/rrtheme_tab_selected_holo" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/rrtheme_tab_unselected_focused_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/rrtheme_tab_selected_focused_holo" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rrtheme_tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rrtheme_tab_selected_pressed_holo" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rrtheme_tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rrtheme_tab_selected_pressed_holo" />
</selector>
```

This is what it currently looks like:
[image]

All I'm trying to do is change this blue color to green!

Many thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to take a look at this:
[Customize Tab indicator](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs) (dead link)

Also to have your tab customized use [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4,100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6,100&tabColor=00ff13,100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF,100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5,100). I always use it to have my Tabs in the color I want.

Hope I helped you

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for your help. Since i'm using the deprecated TabActivity this needs updating to use fragments and a page viewer first. I'll probably hit this next so I'll post my method when it's done.