# How can I reduce the padding in tabs of tablayout in Titanium tabgroup on Android?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have five tabs (`Events`, `Groups`, `Devices`, `Map`, and `More`) in a `tabgroup` component on Android using Titanium.  I don't want the user to have to scroll horizontally to see these tabs on common, larger android devices.

If I can change the minimum width or padding of a tab, they would easily fit and still be plenty large enough to tap on.

I need to change these style attributes on the Titanium component somehow:

[android.support.design:tabMinWidth](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#attr_android.support.design:tabMinWidth) 
[android.support.design:tabPaddingStart](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#attr_android.support.design:tabPaddingStart)

I can't figure out how.  I see how to create a theme but I don't see how to modify all tablayout components using a theme.

I see that if I had access to the underlying native component I could change the padding doing something like this:

```
int tabIndex = 0; 
LinearLayout layout = ((LinearLayout)((LinearLayout)mTabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(tabIndex)); 
layout.setPadding(0,0, 0, 0);
```

But of course I have no idea how I would do that within the Titanium framework.

Any ideas would be appreciated?

Comment: May be this will help you ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647330/cannot-remove-padding-from-tabs-when-using-custom-views-with-tab-layout

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  I am aware of tabPaddingStart/tabPaddingEnd but how do I apply them within Appcelerator Titanium?

Answer (score 0):

You can use titanium platform folder to define
Your custom styles your_project/app/platform/android/....

Here are described how to style:
[Styling Tab Widget's using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231234/styling-tab-widgets-using-xml)

Comment: I am aware that you can style the tab widget using XML to change its colors.  I don't see how to change the padding as a style.  Do you have an example?